# Converting character-level spans to token-level spans

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm currently trying to convert character-level spans to token-level spans and am wondering if there's a functionality in the library that I may not be taking advantage of.

The data that I'm currently using consists of "proper" text (I say "proper" as in it's written as if it's a normal document, not with things like extra whitespaces for easier split operations) and annotated entities. The entities are annotated at the character level but I would like to obtain the tokenized subword-level span.

My plan was to first convert character-level spans to word-level spans, then convert that to subword-level spans. A piece of code that I wrote looks like this:

```
new_text = []
for word in original_text.split():
    if (len(word) > 1) and (word[-1] in ['.', ',', ';', ':']):
        new_text.append(word[:-1] + ' ' + word[-1])
    else:
        new_text.append(word)

new_text = ' '.join(new_text).split()

word2char_span = {}
start_idx = 0
for idx, word in enumerate(new_text):
    char_start = start_idx
    char_end = char_start + len(word)
    word2char_span[idx] = (char_start, char_end)
    start_idx += len(word) + 1
```

This seems to work well but one edge case I didn't think of is parentheses. To give a more concrete example, one paragraph-entity pair looks like this:

```
>>> original_text = "RDH12, a retinol dehydrogenase causing Leber's congenital amaurosis, is also involved in \
steroid metabolism. Three retinol dehydrogenases (RDHs) were tested for steroid converting abilities: human and \
murine RDH 12 and human RDH13. RDH12 is involved in retinal degeneration in Leber's congenital amaurosis (LCA). \
We show that murine Rdh12 and human RDH13 do not reveal activity towards the checked steroids, but that human type \
12 RDH reduces dihydrotestosterone to androstanediol, and is thus also involved in steroid metabolism. Furthermore, \
we analyzed both expression and subcellular localization of these enzymes."
>>> entity_span = [139, 143]
>>> print(original_text[139:143])
'RDHs'
```

This example actually returns a `KeyError` when I try to refer to `(139, 143)` because the adjustment code I wrote takes `(RDHs)` as the entity rather than `RDHs`. I don't want to hardcode parentheses handling either because there are some entities where the parentheses are included.

I feel like there should be a simpler approach to this issue and I'm overthinking things a bit. Any feedback on how I could achieve what I want is appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand: Do you want to split it into a list of words and then use indexing

Answer (score 0):

Tokenization is tricky. I'd suggest using [`SpaCy`](https://spacy.io/) to process your data as you can access the offset of each token in the source text at character level, which should make mapping of your character spans to tokens straightforward:

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
original_text = "Three retinol dehydrogenases (RDHs) were tested for steroid converting abilities:"

# Process data
doc = nlp(original_text)

for token in doc:
    print(token.idx, token, sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
0   Three
6   retinol
14  dehydrogenases
29  (
30  RDHs
34  )
36  were
41  tested
48  for
52  steroid
60  converting
71  abilities
80  :
```